# youtube liveに字幕をアップロードできません。

Tags: python, python-requests, youtube

```
http://upload.youtube.com/closedcaption?cid=(cid)
```

に字幕をアップロードするデータをPOSTしても、

```
[TIME] Can't parse sequence number
```

と返ってきます。
POSTしたデータ

```
2022-06-12T08:02:00.000 region:reg1#cue1
test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この古めの API のドキュメントはここにあるようです https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6077032

このドキュメントによると、クエリパラメーターとして `seq` が必須です。質問者さんのリクエストには `seq` が含まれていないので `Can't parse sequence number` というエラーに繋がっていると思われます。

> | Name | Description/Usage | Example Fragment |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | seq | Must be contained in all POSTs. Counter for all closed caption data posts. Counter must increase by one between posts of new caption data (it must not be increased for retries). | &seq=123 |